# Geometry dash loading problem

Tags: geometry-dash

I have a problem where everything loads except when I try and load people's profiles, upload levels, or save my game. Everytime I load a profile or try to it will say "Something went wrong" and when I try to upload a level it says that it cant upload it and finally when I try to save it says it cant save or that it didn't save at all. I have tried the following: Restart my computer, use system restore, uninstall and reinstall GD. I don't know anything else I can do. I know its not my internet because on my phone GD loads perfectly fine I'm not sure what to do. 
Also this is GD on Steam

Answer (score -2):

1:This also happened to me. If this happens, I think you should instead play your account on a different device. I know you cant save, but just starting over from a different save is the most simple answer. Reinstalling geometry dash, and then loading from the last save? Im not informed about that.

2: Its the same process as if you cant save.